# count similarities between two arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

Im stuck on a piece of javascript for the last 4 hours!

The question is how do I count similarities between 2 arrays like so:

```
arrayA = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g];
arrayB = [c,d,e];
```

The answer shoud be three. The only piece of code I have at the moment produces a infinite loop :(

Pleas help

Comment: Perhaps you could show the code that produces the infinite loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go (**cross browser solution**):

[note that `.filter()` method wont work in IE8 and other old browsers, so i suggest the following approach]

1) define the function:

```
function count_similarities(arrayA, arrayB) {
    var matches = 0;
    for (i=0;i<arrayA.length;i++) {
        if (arrayB.indexOf(arrayA[i]) != -1)
            matches++;
    }
    return matches;
}
```

2) call it:

```
var similarities = count_similarities(arrayA, arrayB);
alert(similarities + ' matches found');
```

if you don't bother about old browsers support, i'd highly suggest lonesomeday's answer.

hope that helps.

Comment: Indeed this is a good solution, though note that the `filter` code *can* be used in IE8 and before, if you add it with shims.

Comment: @GalV Well, remember that they're only used in the browsers that need them. If you really want to support IE8, then you'd better get rid of `Array#indexOf` as well.

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to filter `arrayA` by checking each to see if it's in `arrayB`, then getting the `length` of the new array:

```
arrayA.filter(function(el) {
    return arrayB.indexOf(el) >= 0;
}).length;
```

This uses:

- [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array#length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length?)

NB that the first two are not available in old browsers, so need to be shimmed using the code in the links given.

Comment: @l2aelba Because it's beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

You should take each element of one array and check if it is present in the other using arrayA.indexOf(arrayB[i])
If it doesnt return -1 then increment a count variable.
At the end count is your answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can go with $.inArray() function to do this

> > http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/

```
        $(function () {                    
            arrayA = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
            arrayB = ['c', 'd', 'e'];
            var matchCount = 0;

            $.each(arrayB, function (index, value) {
                if ($.inArray(value, arrayA) != -1)
                    matchCount++;
            });        

            alert("Matched elements : " + matchCount);
       });
```

Comment: Please expand your answer. In this form it isn't really useful.